# Where were Ben's parents in Better Luck Tomorrow?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, better-luck-tomorrow

Better Luck Tomorrow's action takes place over the course of four months or more, closely following the protagonist high school student Ben, his daily routines as well as changes that happen to them. However, his parents are never shown. He seems to live in a suburban house and his job at the start of the movie is at a fast food place, so it is not likely that he is providing for himself. Later in the movie some things happen to him that are likely to be noticed by his parents:

> He starts having regular drunken parties with his friends on weekends and later even takes up cocaine and overdoses, waking up in a puddle of his own blood.

Why are the reactions of his parents not shown?